# Minimal line integral over a function between two points in $\mathbf{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, soft-question

I don't know where to talk about some made-up problem so this may get closed and I understand it.

A couple of months ago for some reason, this problem came into my head out of nowhere:

> Given two points $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a continuous two-variable function defined on a region $D$ containing $A$ and $B$, what is the line integral on $D$ with endpoints $A$ and $B$ such that it is a minimum?

An analogy is if you're on a mountain (the function $f$), and you're starting at some point (the point $A$), and you want to get to some other point on the mountain (the point $B$), then what path (presumably a vector function) allows you to stay as low (in altitude) as possible?

To clarify further, suppose we have two points, like $(\pm 1/2,0)$ and we have $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. On the 2D plane, we just have [a circle with two points](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tbsfahbuag), and notice that we can draw an infinite number of paths connecting the two points. Now consider the hemisphere in 3D:

[image]

The question is: Find the path such that the line integral between the two points is

1. In the domain of $f$
2. Is a minimum. Out of *every single possible* path, its absolute value must be a minimum.

I chose to minimize a line integral because to me it seems like it is the perfect tool to measure the height of the function across its surface. Also I think that the absolute value should be the thing minimized and not the actual function because being able to go to negative infinity is not as interesting.

To make things a little more explicit:

> Consider the points $(\pm 1/2, 0, \sqrt{3}/2)$ and the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Find the vector function $\mathbf{r}(t) = \langle x(t), y(t) \rangle, a \leq t \leq b$ where $\mathbf{r}(a)=(-1/2,0)$ and $\mathbf{r}(b)=(1/2,0)$ and $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 \leq 1$ for all $t \in [a,b]$  such that the (line) integral $$\int_a^b f(x(t),y(t))\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2} dt$$ is a minimum.

This is what my problem is asking for, but to find the minimal path between ANY two points and ANY function. Generalizing further asks for finding the minimal space curve between two points with a 3-variable function. And this can be taken to $n$-dimensions. I've only actually started working on this right before starting to write this by "degeneralizing" the problem to one dimension:

> Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$. What is the continuous function $g(t), \alpha \leq t \leq \beta$ where $g(\alpha)=a$ and $g(\beta) = b$ such that the integral
> $$
> \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(g(t)) \sqrt{(dg/dt)^2} dt
> $$
> is a minimum?

At this point, the most simple this problem could get was to let $f(x)=1$, $a=0$, and $b=1$. It isn't very hard to show that the function $g$ is just $x$ (actually it's any increasing function $h$ with $h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=1$). So what are your thoughts on this problem? Are there similar ones? Is this already a known problem? Because I tried looking for it but I couldn't so now I'm here. Also, I don't think it's exactly possible to find an explicit path for every function because my ooga booga instincts tell me that this is like finding a formula for the antiderivative of any function.

Edit: For the case where $f(t)=t$, $a=0$, and $b=1$ it turns out that the corresponding $g$ is
$$
g(t) = \left(-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)t+\left(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)t^{2}
$$
Interesting!